# calculate probabilty, Uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

this is my first question so excuse my unknowing and mistakes:
I was reading a book and just faced this thing:

(1.4)   $=P(X\gt Z/2)(Y-X)$

(1.5)   $=P(2X\gt Z)(Y-X)$

(1.6)   $=\min\{{2X,1\}}(Y-X)$

I'm facing difficulty in understanding the transition from equation (1.5) to (1.6).
what is given is that $X$ and $Z$ are uniformly distributed between $[0,1]$.

Comment: Since quite a few readers will be "facing difficulty in understanding" your question, which, as you more or less acknowledged in some comment, makes little sense at present, you might want to add a mention of this at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $2X>1$ then $P(2X>Z)=1$.  If $2X<1$ then $P(2X>Z)=2X$, since $Z$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, what it would be if $X$ and $Z$ where distributed between $[1,2]$?

Comment: If $2X>2$ then $P(2X>Z)=1$. If $2X<2$ then $P(2X>Z)=2X-1$, is this right?

Comment: vadim wrote `If 2X<1 then P(2X>Z)=2X, since Z is uniform on [0,1].`  ??????? This looks wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Consider $2X$ to be a fixed constant less than $1$.  Now choose $Z$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.  The probability it is less than $2X$ is exactly $2X$.  Also, @wolfies, in the future please be civil and specific with your questions and criticism.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not consistent with the information provided. The OP states that X ~ Uniform(0,1) random variable, not a constant. Even then, if the text *was* intending to describe a specific outcome of random variable X, then it would use a lower case x, not an uppercase X. I am not aware of any aspect of the criticism that is or was uncivil.

Answer (score 0):

The proof asserts:  $P(2X\gt Z) = \min\{{2X,1\}}$

and the OP asks why this is so. Neither the proof nor the answer above make any sense to me.

If X ~ Uniform(0,1) and Z ~ Uniform(0,1) are independent, then $P(2X\gt Z)$ = $\frac{3}{4}$.
By contrast, $\min\{{2X,1\}}$ = 2X if x < $\frac{1}{2}$, and 1 otherwise. It is not a constant, nor a probability: it is a random variable.

Comment: You are pointing that the book is wrong?

Comment: yup (unless it has been quoted incorrectly)

Comment: no, the quotation is correct.

Comment: What is the book seeking to prove? What is the proof for? Do you have a reference, or can you quote the whole proof please.

Comment: It's a first price auction utility maximization, where $X$ is the bid of player $1$ and $Z$ is the bid of player $2$ and $Y$ is the value of the good for player $1$

Comment: And, would it be correct to say then that we are maximising the utility of player 1, by choosing bid x? If so, x is not a random variable at all: it is a choice variable, and both the notation used in the proof, and your assertion that X is a Uniform(0,1) random variable would be false.

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake. you are right, that would fix everything, thanks.